# How to map the indexes of a matrix to a 1-dimensional array (C++)?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, matrix

I have an 8x8 matrix, like this:

```
char matrix[8][8];
```

Also, I have an array of 64 elements, like this:

```
char array[64];
```

Then I have drawn the matrix as a table, and filled the cells with numbers, each number being incremented from left to right, top to bottom.

If I have, say, indexes 3 (column) and 4 (row) into the matrix, I know that it corresponds to the element at position 35 in the array, as it can be seen in the table that I've drawn. I believe there is some sort of formula to translate the 2 indexes of the matrix into a single index of the array, but I can't figure out what it is.

Any ideas?

Comment: `arr[i*cols+j]` for equivalent `matrix[i][j]` indexing, assuming you want row-major ordering, and `cols` is your defined row width in columns (in your example's case, `8`).

Comment: I've tried all kinds of simple calculations like multiplying row * column * 8, dividing, etc. but it doesn't work. I'm not very good at math.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

The way most languages store multi-dimensional arrays is by doing a conversion like the following:

If `matrix` has size, n (rows) by m (columns), and we're using "[row-major ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-_and_column-major_order)" (where we count along the rows first) then:

`matrix[ i ][ j ] = array[ i*m + j ]`.

Here i goes from 0 to (n-1) and j from 0 to (m-1).

So it's just like a number system of base 'm'.  Note that the size of the last dimension (here the number of rows) doesn't matter.

---

For a conceptual understanding, think of a (3x5) matrix with 'i' as the row number, and 'j' as the column number.  If you start numbering from `i,j = (0,0) --> 0`.  For *'row-major'* ordering (like this), the layout looks like:

```
           |-------- 5 ---------|
  Row      ______________________   _ _
   0      |0    1    2    3    4 |   |
   1      |5    6    7    8    9 |   3
   2      |10   11   12   13   14|  _|_
          |______________________|
Column     0    1    2    3    4
```

As you move along the row (i.e. increase the column number), you just start counting up, so the Array indices are `0,1,2...`.  When you get to the second row, you already have `5` entries, so you start with indices `1*5 + 0,1,2...`.  On the third row, you have `2*5` entries already, thus the indices are `2*5 + 0,1,2...`.

For higher dimension, this idea generalizes, i.e. for a 3D `matrix` L by N by M:

`matrix[ i ][ j ][ k ] = array[ i*(N*M) + j*M + k ]`

and so on.

---

For a really good explanation, see: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/arrays/; or for some more technical aspects: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order

Comment: I can't believe it was so simple... Very informative, thank you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the current description is correct (as also described by @user1480848's answer below --- and corresponding edit on Mar 4, 2014).  Please leave a comment if you don't think so - instead of editing the answer directly.

Comment: @DilithiumMatrix shouldn't the formula be `j + (i * n)` and not `i + (j * n)` as you suggest? Consider coordinates `2,3`, which should return 13 using your matrix: `3 + (2 * 5) = 13`. If we used your formula instead, we would get `2 + (3 * 5) = 17`. Am I missing something?

Comment: @Mohamad absolutely, thanks!  That's also what user1480848 described below... I think I must have rolled back to the wrong edit.  ***Should*** be fixed now.  I hope.

Comment: And just to be sure because it's not always the same convetion, by 'n' you mean number of rows and 'm' the number of columns, right?

Comment: @TMOTTM, yes that's right.  I tried to clarify the answer.

Answer (score 14):

For row-major ordering, I believe the statement `matrix[ i ][ j ] = array[ i*n + j ]` is wrong.

The offset should be `offset = (row * NUMCOLS) + column`.

Your statement results to be `row * NUMROWS + column`, which is wrong.

The links you provided give a correct explanation.

Comment: Are you responding to zhermes' answer? If so you should probably just edit his/her post with your correction.

Comment: He is correct, you are probably setting up the (raw)array column major way in your head :)

Answer (score 7):

Something like this?

```
//columns = amount of columns, x = column, y = row
var calculateIndex = function(columns, x, y){
    return y * columns + x;
};
```

The example below converts an index back to x and y coordinates.

```
//i = index, x = amount of columns, y = amount of rows
var calculateCoordinates = function(index, columns, rows){
    //for each row
    for(var i=0; i<rows; i++){
        //check if the index parameter is in the row
        if(index < (columns * i) + columns && index >= columns * i){
            //return x, y
            return [index - columns * i, i];
        }
    }
    return null;
};
```

Comment: Perhaps you could you explain a little of how this relates to (and answers) the OP's original question?

Comment: I should read a little better. It actually does the exact opposite as what the OP has asked for. This converts 35,8,8 to 3,4.

Comment: Now it illustrates both conversions :)

Comment: Although I had to swap row and columns for my use but this is exactly what I was looking for.