# Pointer to Multidimensional Array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Can a pointer to a multidimensional array in C be written simply as:

```
double *array;
```

Where `array`is an n by n matrix?

And then can I access the element in row `i`, column `j`, by `array[i][j]`?

Or is there such thing as a double pointer?

Comment: There *is* such a thing as a `**` , but it's not the same as a `[][]` at all.

Comment: You would have to declare as `array[rows * columns]` (or allocate memory for) and index by `[row * columns + col]`

Comment: Pointer is a pointer. Pointer to anything in C is represented in the same way, so if you want, you can cast them. But it is strongly not recommended.  Multidimensional arrays are usually represented as pointers to other pointers.

Answer (score 5):

> Can a pointer to a multidimensional array in C be written simply as:

```
double *array;
```

Yes.

Say you have `M x N` array. You can use:

```
double* array = malloc(M*N*sizeof(*array));
```

Then, you can access the elements by using:

```
size_t getArrayIndex(size_t m, size_t n, size_t M)
{
    return (m*M+n);
}

double getArrayElement(double* array, size_t m, size_t n, size_t M)
{
    return array[getArrayIndex(m, n, M)];
}
```

Comment: @user3746892 See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015556/how-to-map-the-indexes-of-a-matrix-to-a-1-dimensional-array-c, although it is of c ++ the answer can help you better understand this answer

Answer (score 2):

`double *` is a pointer to a `double`. It's also pointer to an element of an array of `double`.

To do what you want:

```
double bla[23][42];          // array of arrays, type is double [23][42]
double (*p)[23][42] = &bla;  // pointer to an object of type double [23][42]
```

Answer (score 0):

to make a pointer to a multidimensional array `array[i][j]` where i is number of rows and j is number columns you can do `double (*ptr)[j]` which says that ptr is a pointer to double array of j elements. then you can assign `ptr=array;`

Answer (score -1):

> Can a pointer to a multidimensional array in C be written simply as:
>
> ```
> double *array;
> ```

That *could be* something that is used to represent an array, when handing it over to a function! A C array is then only represented by a pointer to its first element. How these elements are organized internally is up to you; making sure you don't use indices that are actually outside the array, too.

> Or is there such thing as a double pointer?

Of course; `double ***ndim_array` is perfectly valid. However, you could also use multidimensional arrays like `double [][][]`.

(Thanks to all the contributors in comments!)

Comment: @EOF: yep, you're right of course with the "a pointer is not an array"; I think I'm pretty correct on `double[][]` actually having to be read as "an array of arrays", ie. a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: No. It's a multidimensional array. They really, really are different.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: No, you've got it wrong. An array is not a pointer, and an array of arrays is not a pointer to a pointer. Check out the FAQ: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy: that FAQ has a nice explanation! Note, though, that I've used the verb *represent* deliberately. Ok, you've got me on the multidimensional array thing, indeed, though, so I'm removing this from my answer. Thanks, guys! BTW; if you can, you're absolutely welcome to correct my answer here.