# CUDA reduce find max

Tags: c++, cuda, reduce

I am trying to write my own implementation of reductive search for maximum number. This is my first CUDA C program and I ran into some errors that I cannot understand yet.

my code:

```
__global__
void reduce (box * d_in_data, int insize, box * d_out_data)
{
    /*
    for example:

    array size = 25200 (size variable, keep in d_in_data)
    gridDim = 252
    blockDim = 10
     */

    uint32_t tid = threadIdx.x;

    //__shared__ box sdata[insize / gridDim.x]; // 25200 / 252 = 100

    extern __shared__ box sdata[]; // 25200 / 252 = 100

    /*spt its 'size per thread' for filling sdata*/

    /* (25200 / 252) / 10 */ /* each thread should be copy 10 elements from d_in_data to sdata  */

    uint32_t spt = (insize / gridDim.x) / blockDim.x;

    box (* sh_ptr)[blockDim.x][spt] = (box (*) [blockDim.x][spt]) &sdata;

    for (int i = 0;i < spt;i++){

        (*sh_ptr)[tid][i] = d_in_data[blockIdx.x * (insize / gridDim.x) + (tid * blockDim.x + i)];

    }
    __syncthreads();
    box temp = (*sh_ptr)[tid][0];
    for (int i = 0;i < spt;i++){
        box i_box = (*sh_ptr)[tid][i];

        temp = temp.s < i_box.s ? i_box : temp;
    }

    (*sh_ptr)[tid][0] = temp;
    __syncthreads();
    box (* d_out_ptr)[gridDim.x][blockDim.x] =  (box (*)[gridDim.x][blockDim.x]) d_out_data;
    (*d_out_ptr)[blockIdx.x][tid]  = (*sh_ptr)[tid][0];
    
}
```

1. `__shared__ box sdata[insize / gridDim.x];` - why *"here cannot be used as a constant"* ? how to set the size explicitly?
2. `box (* sh_ptr)[blockDim.x][spt] = (box (*) [blockDim.x][spt]) &sdata;` - *"error: expression must have a constant value"* , *"note: attempt to access run-time storage"*, *"note: the value of variable "spt""*.
   How to write correctly in my case?
3. `uint32_t spt = (insize / gridDim.x) / blockDim.x;` - *"here cannot be used as a constant"*
4. `box (* d_out_ptr)[gridDim.x][blockDim.x] =  (box (*)[gridDim.x][blockDim.x]) d_out_data;` - *"error: expression must have a constant value"* , *"note: attempt to access run-time storage"*, It's the same here.

Please tell me where I made a mistake in each paragraph.

Comment: 1 and 3: you need compile time constant. 2 and 4: just use reference to the array instead of doing complex indexing.

Answer (score 2):

Your errors have nothing to do with CUDA.

- `__shared__ box sdata[insize / gridDim.x];` *- why "here cannot be used as a constant" ? how to set the size explicitly?*

   In C/C++ the array size must be known at compile time. Here, `insize / gridDim.x` would have to be known at compile time, but `insize` is certainly not.

  ```
  extern __shared__ box sdata[];
  ```

  looks completely OK to me. If you need the size of this array (you certainly do), you can compute it at runtime form function arguments etc.
- `box (* sh_ptr)[blockDim.x][spt] = (box (*) [blockDim.x][spt]) &sdata;` *- "error: expression must have a constant value" , "note: attempt to access run-time storage", "note: the value of variable "spt"". How to write correctly in my case?*

  Here you try to define a pointer to a 2D array. This is possible only if the last dimension of the array is known at compile time, but `spt` is not known.  To  circumvent it, you need to calculate the address into the shared memory (`sdata`) yourself. This is a 1D array and treat it this way.
- Error number 3 seems to be a diagnostic message, not an error.
- Error number 4 is of the same type as Error nr 2.

For further reading see, for example, [Pointer to Multidimensional Array in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351093/pointer-to-multidimensional-array-in-c)