# Create matrix in c++. FOR statement alternative

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to create a matrix in C++. I am a beginner. Is there any other simple way to done this? I am refering to the `for` statement which uses `cin` (something like `for (i,j=1; i,j<=n; i,j++)` or `cin >> a;`)

```
int n=5;
int a[n][n];

for(int i=1; i<=n; i++) {
    for(int j=1; j<=n; j++) {
        cin >> a[i][j];
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: indices start from zero !!

Comment: There is always other way to do this, but your is good. It is easier to read than a for(int i=0;i<n*n) { cin >> a[i%n][i/n] }
By the way, you have a bug : In computer science, start is often 0, not 1 (except for some obscur and strange language)

Comment: Arrays go from `0` to `n - 1`. Also, `int a[n][n]` is not standard C++ when `n` is not a constant expression (although this is supported on some compilers as an extension).

Comment: Simple for the user or simple to program?   You could ask the user to provide a file with the desired contents (which you'd have to open/read/parse/validate/etc) and use the contents to populate the matrix.   That might be easier for the user, though quite a bit more complicated for the programmer.

Comment: You can store the matrix in one dimension.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015556/how-to-map-the-indexes-of-a-matrix-to-a-1-dimensional-array-c

Comment: Thank you for your comments! Thanks @A.H too!

Comment: I learn C++ at highschool. I know, but my teacher said we must start from "1" because in a real matrix there doesn't exists a 0 line.

Comment: Your teacher is wrong. If you access the value at position n, your program will misbehave. Indices in C++ arrays/matrices start from 0 and go to n-1, period.

Comment: Thank you @CássioRenan ! I underestand.

Comment: You can also pay attention to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/array/array/