# Expression Template performance for deep nested expressions

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-optimization, expression-templates

I am investigating expression template performance in matrix multiplication. I am unrolling the loop in the matrix multiplication, and I find that the performance of native doubles is equal to that of the expression templates until the depth of the expression gets too large, and the expression template performance goes downhill. Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

template<typename T>
struct Real
{
   typedef T RealType;

    Real() noexcept : m_real(0) {}
    inline explicit Real(RealType real) noexcept
        : m_real(real)
   {
   }

    inline RealType value() const noexcept
    {
        return m_real;
    }                                           

    template<typename Expr>
    void operator+=(const Expr& expr)
    {
        m_real += expr.value();
    }

    RealType m_real;
};

#define DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATOR(NAME, OP)      \
    template<typename Expr1, typename Expr2>                            \
    struct NAME                                                         \
    {                                                                   \
        typedef typename Expr1::RealType RealType;                      \
                                                                        \
        NAME() noexcept {}                                              \
        NAME(const Expr1& e1, const Expr2& e2) noexcept                 \
            : m_e1(e1), m_e2(e2) {}                                     \
                                                                        \
        inline RealType value() const noexcept                          \
        {                                                               \
            return m_e1.value() OP m_e2.value();                        \
        }                                                               \
                                                                        \
        Expr1 m_e1;                                                     \
        Expr2 m_e2;                                                     \
    };                                                                  \
    template<typename Expr1, typename Expr2>                            \
    inline decltype(auto) operator OP (const Expr1& e1, const Expr2& e2) noexcept\
    {                                                                   \
        return NAME<Expr1, Expr2>(e1, e2);                              \
    }                                                                   \

DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATOR(Multiply, *)
DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATOR(Add, +)
DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATOR(Subtract, -)
DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATOR(Divide, /)

template<typename T>
struct Matrix
{
    explicit Matrix(size_t size)
        : m_matrix(size, std::vector<T>(size))
    {
    }
    explicit Matrix(size_t size, const T& intialVal)
        : m_matrix(size, std::vector<T>(size, intialVal))
    {
    }
    std::vector<T>& operator[](size_t row) { return m_matrix[row]; }
    const std::vector<T>& operator[](size_t row) const { return m_matrix[row]; }
    size_t size() const { return m_matrix.size(); }

    std::vector<std::vector<T> > m_matrix;
};

#define MATRIX_MULT_KERNEL(N) m1[i][k+N] * m2[j][k+N]
#define MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(N) \
   MATRIX_MULT_KERNEL(N) + MATRIX_MULT_KERNEL(N+1) + MATRIX_MULT_KERNEL(N+2) + MATRIX_MULT_KERNEL(N+3)

template<typename T>
Matrix<T> operator*(const Matrix<T>& m1, const Matrix<T>& m2)
{
    if (m1.size() != m2.size())
        throw std::runtime_error("wrong sizes");

    Matrix<T> m3(m1.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < m1.size(); ++i)
        for (size_t j = 0; j < m1.size(); ++j)
            for (size_t k = 0; k < m1.size(); k+=16)
            {
                auto v0 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(0);
                auto v1 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(4);
                auto v2 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(8);
                auto v3 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(12);
                // auto v4 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(16);
                // auto v5 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(20);
                // auto v6 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(24);
                // auto v7 = MATRIX_MULT_ADD_KERNELS_4(28);
                auto expr = (v0 + v1 + v2 + v3);// + v4 + v5 + v6 + v7);
                m3[i][j] += expr;

            }
    return m3;
}

decltype(auto) now()
{
    return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
}

decltype(auto) milliseconds(const decltype(now())& start, const decltype(now())& end)
{
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count();
}

int main()
{
    constexpr static const int SIZE = 1024;
    {
        Matrix<double> m1(SIZE, 1.0);
        Matrix<double> m2(SIZE, 1.0);
        auto begin = now();
        Matrix<double> m3 = m1 * m2;
        auto end = now();
        std::cout << milliseconds(begin, end) << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
    {
        Matrix<Real<double> > m1(SIZE, Real<double>(1.0));
        Matrix<Real<double> > m2(SIZE, Real<double>(1.0));
        auto begin = now();
        Matrix<Real<double> > m3 = m1 * m2;
        auto end = now();
        std::cout << milliseconds(begin, end) << "ms" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

If I uncomment out the code in the matrix multiplication loop, and increment k by 32, the expression templates takes three times longer. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

I'm compiling on GCC 5.4 on cygwin on an Intel Xeon E3-1225 V2.

Comment: What compiler options you are using? Probably the best way to find out what the compiler does is to take a look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry. -std=c++14 -O3

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea how to read assembly.

Answer (score 0):

There are three reasons.

First, you're mixing templates and macros.  It might be easier to create the `DEFINE_BINARY_OPERATOR` macro and so forth, but you'll also lose some optimization.  There's probably a way to get the compiler to generate the classes through templates of templates, which might allow the compiler to do some magic it can't through macros.

Second, you're using a two-dimensional vector.  The [C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/operator-overloading#matrix-array-of-array) explains that trying to make a Matrix class look like an array-of-an-array can lead to performance problems.  In this case, you're trying to build a 3-D matrix; it might be cheaper and easier if you built it in with the `()` operator for the general case rather than the `[][]` operator for the specific case. The same section explains how to implement a Matrix class in a more generalized, efficient manner.

There's a mathematical way to "fake" a multidimensional array using a single-dimensional array.  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14015556/how-to-map-the-indexes-of-a-matrix-to-a-1-dimensional-array-c) explains how, and the single level of indirection will reduce some overhead too.

Third, there's a lot of overhead from that `vector` class that you probably don't need.  This might be one isolated case where it's better just to use an array instead of a `vector`, simply because you aren't getting much benefit from the vector besides a bit better ease of use.

Finally, that loop, unfortunately, has polynomial complexity.  That means any performance problems you have from the above are going to be cubed.  For a small array, it's not a big deal, but for a big array, that could get expensive.  Perhaps there are some optimization flags you need to turn on or off to reduce this problem.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think your comments are relevent. It doesn't matter that I'm using macros - the preprocessor expands them to code; that has nothing to do with the performance. My implementation of `Matrix` also has nothing to do with the question at hand.